# Differentiable Functions / Zorich

Tags: real-analysis

A body that can be regarded as a point mass is sliding down a smooth hill under the influence of gravity. The hill is the graph of a differentiate function *y = f(x).*

a) Find the horizontal and vertical components of the accleration vector that
the body has at the point $(x_0, y_0)$.
 b) For the case *f(x) =* $x^2$ when the body slides from a great height, find the
point of the parabola *y =* $x^2$ at which the horizontal component of the acceleration is maximal.

I've tried but i don't even know where to begin. Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mass is always on the graph. The acceleration is directed down the slope (downhill down the tangent), and basic physics tells you, that the magnitude of the acceleration is proportional to the sine of the slope angle.

A normalized vector along the tangent is $(\cos\alpha,\sin\alpha)$, when expressed with slope angle $\alpha$. Acceleration is thus
$$\vec{a}=-(\cos\alpha\sin\alpha,\sin^2\alpha)$$

Take into account $\tan\alpha=f'(x)$ and you get
$$\vec{a}=-\frac{(f'(x),f'(x)^2)}{1+f'(x)^2}$$

Sanity checks: $f(x)=\rm const$ gives you no acceleration. Infinite slope $f'(x)=\infty$ gives you $\vec{a}=(0,-1)$ which is ok.